# Get Zip file size overr FTP Connection in Java

Tags: java

I'm sending zip file over FTP connection so to fetch file size , I have used :

```
URLConnection conn = imageURL.openConnection();
long l = conn.getContentLengthLong();
```

But it returns -1

Similarly for files sent over Http request , I get correct file size.

How to get correct file size in ftp connection in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

> for files sent over Http request , I get correct file size.

MAYBE. `URLConnection.getContentLength[Long]` returns specifically the content-length *header*. HTTP (and HTTPS) supports several different ways of delimiting bodies, and depending on the HTTP options and versions the server implements, it *might* use a content-length header or it might not.

Somewhat similarly, an FTP server *may* provide the size of a 'retrieved' file at the beginning of the operation, or it may not. But it *never* uses a content-length header to do so, so `getContentLength[Long]` doesn't get it. However, the implementation code does store it internally if the server provides it, and it can be extracted by the following quite ugly hack:

```
    URL url = new URL ("ftp://anonymous:dummy@192.168.56.2/pub/test"); 
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    try( InputStream is = conn.getInputStream() ){
        if( ! conn.getClass().getName().equals("sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection") ) throw new Exception("conn wrong");
        Field fld1 = conn.getClass().getDeclaredField("ftp"); 
        fld1.setAccessible(true); Object ftp = fld1.get(conn);
        if( ! ftp.getClass().getName().equals("sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient") ) throw new Exception ("ftp wrong");
        Field fld2 = ftp.getClass().getDeclaredField("lastTransSize");
        fld2.setAccessible(true); long size = fld2.getLong(ftp);
        System.out.println (size);
    }
```

Hacking undocumented internals may fail at any time, and versions of Java above 8 progressively discourage it: 9 through 15 give a warning message about illegal access unless you use `--add-opens` to permit it and 16 makes it an error (i.e. fatal). Unless you *really* need the size before reading the data (which implicitly gives you the size) I would not recommend this.